# EmberJS populate dropdown from another model

Tags: ember.js

I am a completely newbie in EmberJS. I am trying to make a simple app with two entities, users and departments. I have separate templates and routes for users CRUD, and for department CRUD.

Here is the detailed code about my model

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: 'App.ApplicationAdapter'
});


DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  host: 'http://localhost:8081/slim'
});


App.Department = DS.Model.extend({
    departmentname : DS.attr(),
    user           : DS.hasMany('user')
});


App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  username     : DS.attr('string'),
  full_name    : DS.attr(),
  email        : DS.attr(),
  department_id   : DS.belongsTo('department')
});
```

In read mode, I can show which department a user is in, using this

```
Department: {{department_id.departmentname}}
```

However, in user edit / user create mode, I want to display a dropdown here showing the departments. **I do not know how to do this because when defining the 'users' route I specified the model to be App.User**.

I tried this but no success

```
{{view Ember.Select content=model.departments}}
```

My code uses a PHP rest api, so it wont run on jsbin. But still I am putting the link

http://jsbin.com/oViJeyAy/2/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't necessary in newer versions of ED (1.0 beta 1+)

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: 'App.ApplicationAdapter'
});

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  host: 'http://localhost:8081/slim'
});
```

It should just be this

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:8081/slim'
});
```

Just add a property to the controller and fetch the departments

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    departments: function(){
        return this.store.find('department');
    }.property(),

    isEditing : false,

    edit: function(){
        this.set('isEditing', true);
    },

    doneEditing: function(){
        this.set('isEditing', false);
        var user = this.get('model');
        user.save();
    }
});
```

Then in your user template

```
{{view Ember.Select 
       content=departments
       optionValuePath="content.id"
       optionLabelPath="content.departmentname"}}
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html

PS Here's a helpful short read on changes for Ember Data 1.0 beta+ https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: The dropdown is populated with the following strings, <App.Department:ember294:8>, <App.Department:ember295:2> .... the number of departmnets match the dropdown items, so I guess the controller is fetching the departments correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I figured you were already looking at the docs, I added a link above with an example